# classification report using prediction generator method

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning

So I am making an indigenous language translator using a per letter data sets. I have minimal knowledge on machine learning and only have made a 2 category image classifier. originally these are my codes it works fine but could only show me the confusion matrix I needed the classification report like F1 scores but I can't seem to wrap my head around it how I should manipulate my codes.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from tensorflow import keras, metrics
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, GlobalAveragePooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
import itertools
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from webencodings import labels
from PIL import ImageFile
ImageFile.LOAD_TRUNCATED_IMAGES = True

train_path=r'C:\Users\Acer\imagerec\BAYBAYIN\TRAIN'
valid_path=r'C:\Users\Acer\imagerec\BAYBAYIN\VAL'
test_path=r'C:\Users\Acer\imagerec\BAYBAYIN\TEST'

class_labels=['A', 'BA', 'KA', 'GA', 'HA', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7',
              '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19',
              '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '28', '29', '30', '31', '32',
              '33', '34', '35', '36', '37', '38', '39', '40', '41', '42', '43', '44']

train_batches=ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=keras.applications.xception.preprocess_input)\
    .flow_from_directory(train_path, target_size=(299,299),classes=class_labels,batch_size=5)
valid_batches=ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=keras.applications.xception.preprocess_input)\
    .flow_from_directory(valid_path, target_size=(299,299),classes=class_labels,batch_size=5)
test_batches=ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=keras.applications.xception.preprocess_input)\
    .flow_from_directory(test_path, target_size=(299,299),classes=class_labels,batch_size=5, shuffle=False)

base_model=keras.applications.vgg19.VGG19(include_top=False)

x=base_model.output
x=GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
x=Dense(1024, activation='relu')(x)
x=Dense(48, activation='softmax')(x)
model=Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=x)


base_model.trainable = False

N=1

print("HANG ON LEARNING IN PROGRESS...")

model.compile(Adam(lr=.0001),loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
history=model.fit_generator(train_batches, steps_per_epoch=1290, validation_data=valid_batches,
                            validation_steps=90,epochs=N,verbose=1)

print("[INFO]evaluating model...")

test_labels=test_batches.classes
predictions=model.predict_generator(test_batches, steps=28, verbose=1)


import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


plt.imshow(np.random.random((48,48)), interpolation='nearest')
plt.xticks(np.arange(0,48), ['A', 'BA', 'KA', 'GA', 'HA', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7',
              '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19',
              '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '28', '29', '30', '31', '32',
              '33', '34', '35', '36', '37', '38', '39', '40', '41', '42', '43', '44'])
plt.yticks(np.arange(0,48),['A', 'BA', 'KA', 'GA', 'HA', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7',
              '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19',
              '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '28', '29', '30', '31', '32',
              '33', '34', '35', '36', '37', '38', '39', '40', '41', '42', '43', '44'])



plt.show()
model.save("X19baybayin.h5")
```

how do i use predictions or can I use it as my y-pred and what should i use for y-true

Answer (score 3):

TL;DR

1. test_batches.classes as *y_true*
2. np.argmax(predictions, axis=-1) as *y_pred*

---

I will assume that you have one class per sample because you are using 'softmax' and 'categorical_crossentropy', and you need to get the best relevant (one) class for each sample (multi-class classification problem).

To clarify:

```
# import classification_report
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report

# get the ground truth of your data. 
test_labels=test_batches.classes 

# predict the probability distribution of the data
predictions=model.predict_generator(test_batches, steps=28, verbose=1)

# get the class with highest probability for each sample
y_pred = np.argmax(predictions, axis=-1)

# get the classification report
print(classification_report(test_labels, y_pred))
```

Note: predict_generator is going to be deprected, use model.predict instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
#you can unpack the step of creating the generator 
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=keras.applications.xception.preprocess_input)
test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(train_path, target_size=(299,299),classes=class_labels,batch_size=5)
##
##your code goes here
##
predictions=model.predict_generator(test_generator, steps=28, verbose=1)
print(classification_report(test_generator[1], predictions))
```

Comment: hiya thanks for helping out, unfortunately, I got this error `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Acer/PycharmProjects/translator/venv/TRY.py", line 65, in <module>
    print(classification_report(test_generator[1], predictions))
NameError: name 'classification_report' is not defined`

Comment: you should import it from sklearn, use: from sklearn.metrics import classification_report

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Acer/PycharmProjects/translator/venv/TRY.py", line 65, in <module>
    print(classification_report(test_generator[1], predictions))
  File "C:\Users\Acer\Anaconda3\envs\TRANSLATOR\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\_classification.py", line 1967, in classification_report
    y_type, y_true, y_pred = _check_targets(y_true, y_pred)`

Comment: `  File "C:\Users\Acer\Anaconda3\envs\TRANSLATOR\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 212, in check_consistent_length
    " samples: %r" % [int(l) for l in lengths])
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [2, 140]`

Comment: same here  ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [32, 192]